# Axiomatization of propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that axiom schema $(((\lnot C)\to (\lnot B))\to (((\lnot C)\to B)\to C))$ can be replaced by schema $(\lnot B\to \lnot C)\to (C\to B)$ without altering the class of theorems.

I suppose I should show the axiom schema is equivalent to $(\lnot B\to \lnot C)\to (C\to B)$

Thus I have this $(((\lnot C)\to (\lnot B))\to (((\lnot C)\to B)\to C)) \vdash_{L_2} (\lnot B\to \lnot C)\to (C\to B)$

By deduction theorem, $(((\lnot C)\to (\lnot B))\to (((\lnot C)\to B)\to C)),  (\lnot B\to \lnot C), C\vdash_{L_2} B$

Thus I need B using the left side of $\vdash_{L_2}$.

So far, am I solving the exercise well?

Comment: No, this is the wrong way to start.  So you want to establish $(\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to (C \to B)$, sure, but you aren't restricted to only using $(\lnot C \to \lnot B) \to (\lnot C \to B) \to C$.  You could also use $(\lnot B \to \lnot C) \to (\lnot B \to C) \to B$, or any other instance of the axiom.

Comment: Also you need to do the reverse, that any number of instances of the second axiom implies the former.

Comment: One of these directions is really easy, and one is really hard.

Comment: @DanielV $\implies$ this is the easier right?

Comment: $(X \to Y) \to Z \vdash Y \to Z$ is the easy thing to prove.

Comment: We should know what the other axioms are.  I mean, if the set of axioms which remain constant are not strong enough to prove the deduction meta-theorem, you simply can't show what gets proposed here.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood 'the set of axioms which remain constant are not strong enough' ? I don't understand you. The axioms are: $A\to (B\to A), (\lnot A\to \lnot B)\to((\lnot A\to B)\to(A))$ and $(A\to (B\to C))\to ((A\to B)\to (A\to C))$

Answer (score 1):

I'll use Polish notation, and recast the content of the axiom schema

1. CaCba
2. CCaCbcCCabCac
3. CCNaNbCCNaba

The problem then becomes to show that CCNaNbCCNaba can get replaced with 4. CCNaNbCba, and from {1., 2., CCNaNbCba} 3. can get deduced.

So, assuming {CNaNb, b}, by axiom 1. CNab follows.  By axiom 3. and CNaNb, and CNab, a follows.  Thus, we have {CNaNb, b} yields a.  Then, by axioms 1. and 2., $\vdash$CCNaNbCba follows.  Thus, {1., 2., 3.} yields 4.

For the other direction, you just assume {1., 2., 4.} and then show that 3. follows.  Believe it or not, if you embed the axioms in a powerful enough theorem prover like Prover9, such as the following:

-P(C(x, y)) | -P(x) | P(y). (this works like modus ponens... though it's a bit more complicated)

P(C(x, C(y, x))). (axiom 1)

P(C(C(x, C(y, z)), C(C(x, y), C(x, z)))). (axiom 2)

P(C(C(N(x), N(y)), C(y, x))). (axiom 4)

and have

P(C(C(N(x), N(y)), C(C(N(x), y), x))).

as a goal, P(C(C(N(x), N(y)), C(C(N(x), y), x))). can get deduced in less than a minute.

Note: you can think of P as meaning $\vdash$.

Comment: why Polish notation ?

Comment: @MichelleGarcía I like it.

Comment: @MichelleGarcía If you ever work with functions that have an arity greater than 2, Polish notation or some prefix notation can really work as advantageous.  I also find it easier to find the antecedent of a conditional in Polish notation.  The algorithm for well-formed formulas in Polish notation is simpler.  And also, it's easy to find the principal connective of a well-formed formula in Polish notation.  Plus, letter like 'C' basically abbreviate words like 'conditional'.

Comment: very interesting.